# Cloned Seven/Bartik themes don't show up

Tags: theming, 8

I copied bartik and seven theme from core/theme folder into the /theme folder.

- I renamed both into xbartik and xseven.
- I renamed all the files named bartik to xbartik and seven to xseven.
- I did a find a replace in the info and theme files to the corresponding name change of xbartik and xseven.
- Did a flush cache and it doesnt show up.

What else could I be missing in this process?

Answer (score 0):

> I renamed all the files named bartik to xbartik

When you say all the files, I hope you also did **bartik.schema** in the `/config/schema` folder.

> I did a find a replace in the info and theme files to the
>   corresponding name change of xbartik and xseven.

You need to do this **for all files**, including files like bartik.schema, bartik.libraries.yml bartik.breakpoints.yml.